Is the following pyproject.toml a correct translation of the given setup.py?
I have a template project that I copy to start all of my Python packages, so far I have been using a setup.py.  It seems that the new packages should use pyproject.toml.
Is this toml file equivalent of the latter given setup.py?  Should I change or add anything?
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "package"
version = "1.0.0"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
dependencies = []

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ["package", "package.*"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"package" = ["data/names.csv"]

[tool.setuptools.entry-points.console_scripts]
package = "package.__main__:main"

And, the setup.py is,
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='package',
    version='1.0.0',
    python_requires='>=3.7',
    packages=find_packages(include=['package', 'package.*']),
    package_data={'package': ['data/names.csv']},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'package = package.__main__:main',
        ],
    },
)


Could the down-voters care to explain?
